# Extending JavaEditor in SWT

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I would like to develop an RCP text Area in which a user can write their own custom code in Java. It should have highlighting feature, auto complete etc. Can I extend the inbuilt java editor in SWT?
Or can I extend some other editors like IEdit?

Comment: Yes, you can extend the Java editor. Yes, you can extend the basic Eclipse text editor to do all these things. Yes, there are Eclipse projects which provide ways to do a lot of this for your. Your question is far too broad to answer here.

Comment: I need something in the right direction to start with.

Comment: If you create a new plug-in project in Eclipse the plug-in creation wizard has a basic XML editor as one of the examples that it will create for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only a Java editor in your application, you can reuse the JDT's Java editor and provide your own `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.text.JavaSourceViewerConfiguration` to customize it.

If you are looking to implement an editor for your own language, then you need to implement `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor`